# How would I increase the Author Role to be able to add a new category?

Tags: categories

How do I increase Author Role permissions to be able to add Categories?

Other solutions welcome. We just need guest authors to be able to add categories while ensuring there is not already a existing appropriate category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a plugin like [Capability Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/) or [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/)

Answer (score 6):

Should work from inside your `functions.php`

```
function add_manage_cat_to_author_role() 
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'author' ) )
        return;

    // here you should check if the role already has_cap already and if so, abort/return;

    if ( current_user_can( 'author' ) ) 
    {
        $GLOBALS['wp_roles']->add_cap( 'author','manage_categories' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_manage_cat_to_author_role', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: how would you check if the role has_cap already? Thanks for any pointers

Comment: There should be a `has_cap` function. I'm not really sure on how this a) can be called - do you need to access the `$GLOBALS['wp_roles']` object first or is it a simple global function & b) which arguments/parameters it takes. Best would be to quickly make a cross wp-core file search (using eg. notepad++) and take a look on how it's defined. I'm pretty sure you can also access and modify the `$GLOBALS['wp_roles']` object, but i wouldn't recommend doing that, because it could lead to unexpected behavior if it's needed prior to your modification.

Comment: Testing this, for me it works with `global $current_user; /**/ $current_user->has_cap('cap'); /**/ $current_user->add_cap('cap');`