# How to add a Capability to a User Role?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I am managing a Wordpress network and would like to add the unfiltered_html user capability to the already predefined user role of Admin.  In a standard installation of Wordpress the Admin account would already have this capability but in an MU installation only Super Admins are afforded this capability.  Wordpress [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

How can I augment the Admin role from within a theme or plugin?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/unfiltered-mu/ looks like it may help.  But it works for admins and editors.  If that's not desired maybe the code can be tweaked a little?

Comment: see this A: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13025/how-would-i-increase-the-author-role-to-be-able-to-add-a-new-category

Comment: @Rev. Voodoo Thanks for the suggestion.  This helped shed some light on the subject as adding the capability of unfiltered_html is not enough to allow a role other than Admin or Super admin the ability to post embeds, etc.  The key was un filtering/hooking Wordpress’ KSES:
kses_remove_filters()

Comment: A detail blog:http://goo.gl/xNuafH

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [WP_Role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_role) class,

```
// get the the role object
$role_object = get_role( $role_name );

// add $cap capability to this role object
$role_object->add_cap( $capability_name );

// remove $cap capability from this role object
$role_object->remove_cap( $capability_name );
```

So to address your original question about how to enable Admins to enter SCRIPT and IFRAME tags into post content, you're looking for the 'unfiltered_html' capability, which in Multisite is only granted to Super Admins.

```
// get the the role object
$admin_role = get_role( 'administrator' );
// grant the unfiltered_html capability
$admin_role->add_cap( 'unfiltered_html', true );
```

or you can run this once in your functions:

```
/* Roles & Capabilities */
add_role('professional', 'Professional User', array(
    'read' => true, // True allows that capability, False specifically removes it.
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
    //'edit_published_posts' => true,
    //'publish_posts' => true,
    //'edit_files' => true,
    'upload_files' => true //last in array needs no comma!
));
```

Comment: Thanks Philip. In regards to the WP_Role class when should execute the code? I am guessing this affects the global role object?

I am glad that you brought up the second block of code mentioning that I could run this once in my functions file.  I have found similar solutions on some of the Wordpress support forums but I find it odd to have run once code in a theme or plugin in.  Especially without a check if the change already exists.  Perhaps the role write is actually negligible.  To check for the capability vs just write the capability to the role as your first example shows.

Comment: I'm also interested in how you would execute the WP_Role class if you get a moment free to tell us. Thanks

Comment: @Jonnybojagles & @Osu, check this out: Ultimate Guide to Roles & Capabilities http://www.garyc40.com/2010/04/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/

Comment: I have already read that article in my pursuit, but I did take the opportunity to run through it all again, thank you! Eventually, after dissecting the unfiltered-mu (mentioned above by Rev. Voodoo) plugin I eventually found out that changing roles by adding capabilities is not enough.  I needed to unfilter Wordpress’ KSES filters.

Comment: I prefer adding a comma to the last element in arrays. Even though it may seem irrelevant as it is not necessary to make the code work nor resulting in error(s), it comes handy when using a version control when visualising modifications; you wouldn't see an old line of array item deleted, re-added and highlighted as new with just a comma as addition or change made for that line. Though little, it helps save lots of time when analysing modifications.

Answer (score 2):

In order to allow another role other than Super Admin or Admin (depending if the Wordpress installation is a network/MU instance or not) to add unfiltered html to a post or comment Wordpress’ KSES filter must be removed.

Check if a user has a particular capability.

```
if ( current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) ) { … }
```

If so than remove KSES

```
kses_remove_filters();
```

This functionality is already wrapped up in unfiltered-mu, allowing admins and editors to add unfiltered html.

Comment: The functionality is also wrapped in a plugin register and deregister so that the logic does not need to be preformed on each WP instance.