# How to give "author" user role appropriate capabilities to add PollDaddy polls? WordPress multisite

Tags: multisite, user-roles, capabilities, multisite-user-management, poll

At the moment, users with role "Author" can only view but not add or edit polls. "Editor" and "Administrator" (site administrator) can add and edit polls however.

This is despite the fact that I have explicitly assigned "manage_polls" capability to "Author". I've tried both Advanced Access Manager 1.6.8 and User Role Editor 3.8.1 plugins which claim that they support WordPress multisite. Still, "Author" can't add or edit polls.

I'm using WordPress 3.3.1 multisite. I strongly believe this has to do with multisite because "edit_users" capability does not work as it appears - [How to enable a site administrator to edit users in a WordPress network/ multisite setup?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21334/how-to-enable-a-site-administrator-to-edit-users-in-a-wordpress-network-multisi)

Is this a PollDaddy's plugin bug or WordPress multisite's bug or is there any way I can enable "Author" to add/ edit polls with PollDaddy plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file "polldaddy.php" and look near the first few dozen lines for this:

```
$this->is_admin               = (bool) current_user_can( 'manage_options' );
```

Change that to

```
$this->is_admin               = (bool) current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
```

That would in theory grant authors and above the same access as an admin - you have to test yourself to be sure. See the admin_menu() function for where the menus are set up along with required permission levels.