# Give Editor Access To Sidebar

Tags: widgets, admin, sidebar, user-roles

I want to give the Editor Role access to editing the sidebar and it's contents. I have a text widget in there and in order to edit this text widget the user needs to be an admin - this sucks. How do I grant permission to the Editor Role that will give him access to edit the sidebar?

Comment: This may be related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/how-to-add-a-capability-to-a-user-role

Comment: It seems to be kind of what I'm looking for but I don't understand the code. It looks like hes creating a new user and assigning roles instead of editing a existing user

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `edit_theme_options` capability should allow the user to edit the sidebar as described on this page :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Widgets_SubPanel

Code to add to `functions.php`

```
   $role = get_role('editor'); 
   $role->add_cap('edit_theme_options');
```

**Edit:**

This should work to prevent editor accessing themes or menus

```
function custom_admin_menu() {

    $user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());     
    if (!empty( $user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
        foreach ($user->roles as $role)
            $role = $role;
    }

    if($role == "editor") { 
       remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php' );
       remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'nav-menus.php' ); 
    }       
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_admin_menu');
```

I haven't had chance to test this, but it only removes them from the menu they may still be able to access them by typing in the URL directly.

Comment: That works like a charm but then how do I keep them from accessing menu or themes?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Fatal Error: Call to undefined function remove_menu_page() - Also I'm not worried about them typing it by URL I really doubt somebody is going to be that malicious and even so it's just themes and menus. And I can't +1 your post enough! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry added wrong code it should be `remove_submenu_page` although you still shouldn't have got the fatal error. I have edited my answer and tested and all works fine for me?

Comment: Still getting a fatal error with "remove_submenu_page" - I'm adding it at the top of the Functions.php in my Themes folder is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, what version of WordPress are you currently using?

Comment: I'm running 3.0.4 - I was trying not to upgrade because I keep hearing how buggy it is on both frontend and backend.

Comment: Oh that would be why then was only supported since 3.1.0, I have had no bugs since upgrading...I would always suggest upgrading to latest version to help keep it secure.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to configure this easy as possible, use the Members plugin. The capability you'll need to add is 'edit_theme_options'. Be aware that this will grant more than just the widgets area, this also grants the editor access to the entire Appearance menu. [See here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_theme_options)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

If you want to do this programmatically, you'll need to use add_cap().

```
$editor = get_role('editor');
$editor->add_cap('edit_theme_options');
```

You can throw that code into its own plugin, and your done.
Or put it into **functions.php**.

Comment: And if anyone's using the fairly popular User Role Editor, you can select 'Edit Theme Options'/'edit_theme_options' there, too.