# Limit role to one plugin

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles, capabilities

Is there a way to do this **without** using another plugin and without modifying WP core code:

I want to give the custom plugin I am writing a settings page.  So I will need to add plugin capabilities to the role that uses my plugin.  However, I do not want those users to see or be able to change settings for any other plugins that might be installed.  Just my plugin.

I was hoping there was something like *$role_object->add_cap('update_settings_myPlugin')*, similar to the way capabilities can be mapped to roles for custom post types.

Comment: This [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90781/82166) by *tfrommen* should get you started!

Answer (score 1):

Man.  This was not easy to chase down.  The answers up above absolutely do not work unless you give the user's role very broad "manage_options" capability.  I asked (and answered) the Trac issue here:  [Admin custom option screen not saved unless user manage_options capability](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208216/admin-custom-option-screen-not-saved-unless-user-manage-options-capability/208223#208223)

Anyone in the future who might search/read this - the trick is to leverage that new filter capability to register your required capability for the more narrow "manage options" activity for your specific plugin or theme.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, what you are thinking about doing should work. [`add_menu_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) or related submenu and settings page functions, accept an argument for required capability. For example:

```
add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
```

The third parameter is "The capability required for this menu to be displayed to the user." Set that to some capability of your own invention, then [add that capability to your user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap):

```
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->add_cap( 'can_edit_posts' );
```

[Or to a role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13470/21376):

```
// get the the role object
$role_object = get_role( $role_name );

// add $cap capability to this role object
$role_object->add_cap( $capability_name );
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I was hoping for - thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, once I implemented this (and checked with the "this might be a duplicate" answer as well) -- it does not work.  It appears that the role also must have capability "manage_options" added to it, otherwise upon saving the options for my plugin I get the "Cheatin 'uh?"  error in WP.  I think adding this capability to the role will expose all other theme or plugin options to my users, which is exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue found here, but for my plugin not a theme.  Granting "manage_options" is way too broad, just to allow my plugin settings page to save its options back to the database.  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14365

Comment: I'd have to see your implementation

Comment: It's very similar to: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35165/how-do-i-create-a-custom-role-capability  -- I just add a custom capability to the role, and only show the new admin menu if the user has that role/capability.  However unless the role also has "manage_options" capability (which opens up a huge can of worms) - the "Submit" action of my new options page in Admin will fail.  So that Trac I linked is exactly my problem and I don't see that it was ever fixed by WP.