# How to give capability (publish contributors posts) to author role?

Tags: posts, author, publish

I am not a PHP programmer, just a simple WordPress user.

- How can I allow author role to allow publication of contributors posts?
- What's the technical name for this?

Comment: I may be mistaken but the word that you are looking for may be 'Editor', if you want a user to edit/publish your contributors' posts. Let me write up an answer for you...

Comment: If you're not a developer or at least like to dabble in code, it's probably better to use a plugin.  Try: http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/  You'll want to give them the edit_other_posts capability.  Keep in mind this will let authors edit other authors posts as well.

Comment: @AndrewBartel there is a solution to that issue linked in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best approach is to add the `edit_other_posts` capability to "author" role in plugin/theme activation and remove that capability on plugin/theme deactivation. With this method you only run the task once and you don't need further coding.

Using plugin activation/deactivation:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_activation_function' );
function cyb_activation_function() {

    $author = get_role( 'author' );
    $author->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 

}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_deactivation_function');
function cyb_deactivation_function() {

    $author = get_role( 'author' );
    $author->remove_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 

}
```

Using theme activation/deactivation:

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'cyb_activation_function');
function cyb_activation_function() {

    $author = get_role( 'author' );
    $author->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 

}

add_action('switch_theme', 'cyb_deactivation_function');
function cyb_deactivation_function() {

    $author = get_role( 'author' );
    $author->remove_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 

}
```

Comment: This turned out to be some comprehensive answers to a relatively poor question that has been asked (in way better form) numerous times. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, a role's capabilities can be altered programmatically, but given that you are

> not a PHP programmer, just a simple WordPress user

you will have to make use of a plugin that allows modification of user roles.
There's a bunch out there, but my personal recommendation would be the [Members](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) plugin by Justin Tadlock.

> What's the technical name for this?

Every [role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Roles) has a bunch of [capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) assigned to them.
That's the terms you were looking for.

> How can I allow author role to allow publication of contributors posts?

The capability you need here is [`edit_others_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_others_posts).

Answer (score -1):

The term that you are looking for is *Editor*. If you are referring to a user that can edit/publish your contributors' posts.

You want to learn about Roles and Capabilities via its [codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). In order to have your users with the `Author` user role to be able to edit and publish pending posts, you will need to assign the capability `edit_others_posts` to this role.

Add the following to your `functions.php` file (using [add_cap](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap), code based on [kaiser's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13033/24875)):

```
function add_edit_others_posts_to_author_role() 
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'author' ) )
        return;

    // here you should check if the role already has_cap already and if so, abort/return;

    if ( current_user_can( 'author' ) ) 
    {
        $GLOBALS['wp_roles']->add_cap( 'author','edit_others_posts' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_edit_others_posts_to_author_role', 10, 0 );
```

Or alternatively, you could use a plugin like [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/). You may as well consider that this will allow your author leveled users to edit published posts. There is a good solution posted that [allow Editors to edit pending posts but not draft ones](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95174/allow-editors-to-edit-pending-posts-but-not-draft-ones).

Comment: the parameter for `current_user_can` is a capability and 'author' is not a capability, it is a role. Also, instead of using `$GLOBALS['wp_roles']` it is much better use `get_role` to get the role object you want to modify.

Comment: @cybmeta While it is true that 'author' is not a capability, you can still add a role for the $capability parameter. Glad you shared an improvement to this solution, but not entirely certain if it was necessary to downvote the otherwise correct answer.

Comment: See [notes about passing roles to `current_user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Notes) and read the reference of the function. It is not intended to accept a role as parameter. I'm sorry for the downvote but I really think that your answer is not good.

Comment: See my answer to see why it can not be an edition of yours.